# Use modal class instead of id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog

I wish to use the below modal in multiple area on the same page but because it has id element it works only once, can someone help me here to make it work as many times on a same page?

i tried the following but when click the button nothing opens.

js coxe

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById(".myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

here is the html

```
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <p><?php echo $row['domainid'];?></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and here is the complete working html + js code

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <p><?php echo $row['domainid'];?></p>
                  </div>
                </div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

please someone help me out here. thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements. So to add an event listener to each of them, you need to loop that collection.

Then, if the modal is always the [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) of the button, it is easy to target it.

Another useful targeting method is [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) which I used to target a parent of the `event.target` (the modal).

```js
var btns = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn"));
var spans = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("close"));

btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
  })
})

spans.forEach(function(span) {
  span.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.closest(".modal").style.display = "none";
  })
})

window.onclick = function(event) {
  let modal = event.target.closest(".modal");
  if (modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal 1</button>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>
      Hello 1
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<button class="myBtn">Open Modal 2</button>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>
      Hello 2
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<button class="myBtn">Open Modal 3</button>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>
      Hello 3
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one small issue im facing, by clicking anywhere on the screen the modal gets closed. can it not be only when click on the X?

Comment: Try removing the `window.onclick` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small mistake in your code. You are selecting class `myBtn` using `getElementById`.

Old code:

```
var btn = document.getElementById(".myBtn");
```

New code:

```
var btn = document.getElementByClassName("myBtn"); //Don't use . (dot)
```

Or:

```
var btn = document.querySelector(".myBtn"); //Use . (dot)
```

Comment: still it opens only one time.

Comment: How many times are you using the button with `class="myBtn"` in DOM? Because the code above selects only the first element in the DOM and applies the function only onto it.

Comment: And `document.getElementByClassName` is not defined :-\